# How to remove outliers from list of dataset

Tags: r, dataset, lapply, outliers

I am trying to remove outliers from a list of two dataset:

```
#creation of dataset
repr = list(mtcars, airquality)

#detectig boxplot
g_stats = lapply(repr, function(x) boxplot(x, main = "Boxplot")$out)
```

This is the code that I have applied with lapply:

```
new = lapply(repr, function(x) 
  x[ !(x %in% g_stats), ])
```

unfortunately, I can see that in the new list of datasets, there is no difference at all (there should be a difference in row numbers at least, but I am not to make work the lapply function conditionally to the list with outliers).

I have also tried to build properly the outlier box

```
#for getting the ID corresponding to the values
id_out1 = lapply(repr, function(x) as.data.frame(Boxplot(x, id = TRUE)))

#for getting the real values
out1 = lapply(repr, 
             function(x) as.data.frame(boxplot(x, main = "Boxplot", plot = TRUE)$out))

outliers1 =  NULL
seq = c(1, 2)

names = c('ID', 'value')
for (i in seq_along(seq)) {
  outliers1[[seq[i]]] = if(nrow(id_out1[[i]]) == nrow(out1[[i]]))
  {cbind(id_out1[[i]], out1[[i]])} else {next}
  colnames(outliers1[[seq[i]]]) = names
  }
```

But to me, it is pretty hard to exclude values in a list that conditionally to ID list and values in outliers1 list.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: What should happen when you remove the outliers?  Delete the record (ie the row), Replace the value with NA, replace with another value?

Comment: Rows deletion, this is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`: it's similar to `lapply`, but instead of accepting just one list, it accepts an arbitrary number of lists.

```r
repr = list(mtcars, airquality)
g_stats = lapply(repr, function(x) boxplot(x, main = "Boxplot", plot = FALSE)$out)
sapply(repr, nrow)
# [1]  32 153
repr2 <- Map(function(x, out) x[rowSums(apply(x, 1, `%in%`, out)) == 0,], repr, g_stats)
sapply(repr2, nrow)
# [1] 18 75
```

The data is indeed different:

```r
lapply(repr, head)
# [[1]]
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# [[2]]
#   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
# 2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
lapply(repr2, head)
# [[1]]
#                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.19 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.15 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.30  1  0    4    4
# [[2]]
#    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 4     18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5     NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 6     28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
# 10    NA     194  8.6   69     5  10
# 11     7      NA  6.9   74     5  11
# 12    16     256  9.7   69     5  12
```

---

I think your case is understated, so I'll state an assumption that seems more reasonable:

> You want to remove a row if a value in it is an outlier *relative to its own column*. That is, in your code, a number is considered as an outlier among all columns, but I think you should only consider it an outlier compared with its own column.

For this, a simple function:

```r
anyoutlier <- function(dat) rowSums(sapply(dat, function(z) z %in% boxplot.stats(z)$out)) > 0
anyoutlier(mtcars)
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Which we'll apply to each column of each frame:

```r
repr <- list(mtcars, airquality)
repr2 <- lapply(repr, function(dat) dat[!anyoutlier(dat),])
sapply(repr2, nrow)
# [1]  28 148
sapply(repr, nrow)
# [1]  32 153
lapply(repr2, head)
# [[1]]
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# [[2]]
#   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
# 2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

Comment: thank you so much @r2evans.  So Map is a function that can work on the different lists at the same time (does it belong to the apply family too)? I can see it has a different syntax from apply. Anyway, I will try the code and I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you again, the code works nicely, but I am afraid it cuts off value aspecifically, while it should do this for just those variables where the outliers were detected.

Comment: If you set the plot argument as TRUE, yo can visualize them

Comment: It cuts off values very specifically, based on your initial needs: when you look at the outliers across all columns, you're combining multiple disparate column types. For example, outliers across `gear`, `mpg`, and `hp` (within `mtcars`) run a full spectrum of values, so outliers are just as likely to be due to unnecessarily coarse combination of different values. If you want to remove per-column outliers, then either (a) when you remove an outlier, you will remove all other values on that row; or (b) you cannot use `data.frame` unless all outliers are perfectly on the same rows (unlikely).

Comment: `Map` is specifically within the `apply` family of functions, and in reality the _biggest_ difference in syntax is that `lapply` the data first, `Map` takes the function first. After that, `lapply(1:3, myfunc)` is equivalent to `Map(myfunc, 1:3)`, but while `lapply` can only operate on one vector/list at a time, we can do `Map(myfunc2, 1:3, 11:13)` that effectively calls `myfunc2(1,11)` then `mufunc2(2,12)` then `myfunc2(3,13)`.

Comment: thank you. but if noticed I have updated the outliers list that considers both the ID and the value to drop out. I did this to make a conditioned drop out to be more precise. So I would expect that to find in the new dataset as many deletions as the ID numbers.

Comment: I've made another guess at what I think you ultimately need. If this doesn't work, you will likely need to add clarity and context to your question. @12666727b9